# How come I got two different calendar type of creationDate in PHAsset?

Tags: ios, phasset

I have this code, which try to fetch all the images sorting by the `creationDate`

```
PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
    options.sortDescriptors = @[
        [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES],
    ];

    switch (type) {
        case MMAssetsPhoto:{
            fetch = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeImage options:options];
            break;
        }
        case MMAssetsVideo:{
            options.includeAssetSourceTypes = PHAssetSourceTypeiTunesSynced | PHAssetSourceTypeCloudShared | PHAssetSourceTypeUserLibrary | PHAssetSourceTypeNone;
            fetch = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithMediaType:PHAssetMediaTypeVideo options:options];
            break;
        }
        default:{
            options.includeAssetSourceTypes = PHAssetSourceTypeUserLibrary;
            fetch  = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:options];
            break;
        }
    }
    [fetch enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(PHAsset * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        EkoLog(@"=======");
        EkoLog(@"asset %@", obj);
        EkoLog(@"create date %@", obj.creationDate);
        EkoLog(@"modification date %@", obj.modificationDate);
    }];
```

but this is the log I got for some images

```
=======
asset <PHAsset: 0x10d075bd0> D27FB9E1-53F0-4884-A0EA-C6E839A6A0FB/L0/001 mediaType=1/0, sourceType=1, (4032x3024), creationDate=2017-01-05 11:54:50 +0000, location=0, hidden=0, favorite=0
create date 2017-01-05 11:54:50 +0000
modification date 2017-01-05 11:54:50 +0000
=======
asset <PHAsset: 0x10d075d20> 18EA7D99-9FB7-4941-9E7A-E0C68F5F791B/L0/001 mediaType=1/0, sourceType=1, (4032x3024), creationDate=2560-01-05 14:03:59 +0000, location=0, hidden=0, favorite=0
create date 2560-01-05 14:03:59 +0000
modification date 2017-01-05 14:04:00 +0000
=======
asset <PHAsset: 0x10d075e70> 41871302-553F-4BF0-AA8C-E6AC177E0068/L0/001 mediaType=1/0, sourceType=1, (3024x4032), creationDate=2560-01-05 14:15:57 +0000, location=0, hidden=0, favorite=0
create date 2560-01-05 14:15:57 +0000
modification date 2017-02-04 21:08:48 +0000
```

As you notice there are some image which got `creationDate` to `2560` which is year `2017` in buddhist calendar. This cause the sorting to arrange images with buddhist calendar to be at the end which is wrong.

I don't why it is right this because when I see it from `modificationDate` I got the correct `2017` year

Anyway to solve this?

**UPDATE**

Look like Apple bug to me because in Photos app those images are in 3103 year ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Apple bug. Incorrect date information is stored in the images.  An NSDate is unconnected to a calendar.  You can think of it as a simple wrapper for a count of seconds since 1970.  The log is not printing using different calendars - a date does not have a calendar.  The date for those image is in the **Gregorian** year 2560 - 543 years in the future.

I think that there was a programmer that did not understand the difference between a calendar and a date and stored incorrect date information in meta data of the images.  What is the source of these images?

Comment: I believe those pictures are taken from build-in Camera app